# Rails routing like github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I am using Rails 3.2

I want to have routing pretty much exactly like github, so:

```
root/(username)
root/(username)/(projectname)
root/(username)/(projectname)/issus
```

etc.

I am trying something like this:

```
resources :publishers do
  resources :magazines do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

But that gives routes like this:

```
/publishers/1/magazines/2/photos/3
```

A project I am looking at does the following which seems to work but does not seem to be for me.

```
resources :projects, :constraints => { :id => /[^\/]+/ }, :except => [:new, :create, :index], :path => "/" do
member do
  get "team"
  get "wall"
  get "graph"
  get "files"
end

resources :wikis, :only => [:show, :edit, :destroy, :create] do
  member do
    get "history"        
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the id number (which is rails default) and use a name I suggest the FriendlyId gem.

watch this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

and here is the github page https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

EDIT

This is the article I was looking for, I forgot I bookmarked it months ago.
http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-3-nested-resource-slugs

Comment: Looks interesting.  I'll have to check out that railscast.  I wonder how it's stored internally, and if using a different database matters.

Comment: This is cool. Not exactly what I want but will be helpful. What I am more so looking for is how github works. So that you do not need a url like /users/Jonovono but instead just /Jonovono works.

Answer (score 0):

You must to use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and scope

```
scope '/:username/:projectname', module: 'users/projects', as: 'users_project' do
    resources :issus
    resources :photos
end
```